# Send mail with SMTP_SSL in python

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib, pem

I'm using the following code to send a mail with the certificate. I have a `ca-chain.cert.pem` file from the mail server. How to use this file for signing mail(I have to use this pem file)?

```
m_server = {
        'username': "abc@myserver.io",
        'password': "123435",
        'server': "mail.myserver.io",
        'port': 465,
    }
    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = "Notification"
    message["From"] = "abc@myserver.io"
    message["To"] = "abc@gmail.com"

    email_body = "<p>test</p>"
    message.attach(MIMEText(email_body, "html"))
    
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(m_server['server'], m_server['port']) as server:
        server.set_debuglevel(1)
        server.login(m_server['username'], m_server['password'])
        server.sendmail(m_server['username'], message["To"], message.as_string())
```

ca-chain.cert.pem file: this file is related to the mail server

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFhTCCA22....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFnDCCA4Sg....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use this file for signing mail(I have to use this pem file)?

Mails do not get signed in SMTP. Certificate based signatures for mail are done by the sender with PGP or S/MIME. Then there are key based signatures done by the mail server with DKIM. But all of the various ways to sign need a private key, which is not given here.

My guess is that the given certificates should instead be used to authenticate the SMTP server during the TLS handshake. To specify the certificate one would need a custom SSL context, something like this:

```
import ssl
ctx = ssl.create_default_context(cafile = 'the-certificates-given-to-you.pem')
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(m_server['server'], m_server['port'], context=ctx) as server:
    ...
```

Comment: There's also DKIM where the outgoing mail server adds a cryptographic signature to each message it sends, but again that looks different, and probably isn't what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @tripleee: Yes, DKIM adds a signature. But in DKIM no certificates are involved at all, only a key pair, where the public key is published via DNA and the private key is used in the local MTA to sign the mail. Thus, this does not match the case here at all: plain key vs. certificates, needs private key vs. does not have one, MTA level vs. client. Still, it is a good addition to where signing might be involved so I've added it as "is not DKIM either" to the answer.